# How to update constant buffer patially in OpenGLES

Tags: opengl, rendering, opengl-es

I am wondering what does glMapBufferRange actually do?

I am accessing my constant buffer like this way:

```
Uint8* builtInBuffer = (Uint8*)glMapBufferRange(buffer, 0, builtInBuffer->GetSize(), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_FLUSH_EXPLICIT_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);
```

However, when reading builtInBuffer , all data set preiously are lost. What happend?
Does glMapBufferRange always clear all data in the range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be expected behaviour.

When you map a buffer you are given a pointer, but there are no guarantees that this pointer is to the actual buffer data storage. In particular, since you specified the write and unsynchronized bits, it's OK for the pointer to be to any arbitrary memory which is then written to the actual buffer when you unmap or flush.

In particular, note from [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml):

> No GL error is generated if the pointer is used to query a mapping which excludes this (GL_MAP_READ_BIT) flag, but the result is undefined and system errors (possibly including program termination) may occur.

If you want to read a buffer, map it for reading, not for writing.